# Textfield added to Jframe disappears when the graphics are redrawn

Tags: java, render, textfield

I am having problem with the JFrame textfield.
I am trying to make a word game, but the problem is that when I try to create textfield to set an input and then check if it's the right word, I have got the word thing covered.
The problem is that when I try to add Textfield, it disappears when i render things to JFrame.

```
public teksti() {

    setTitle("Hirsipuu");
    setSize(leveys,korkeus);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setBackground(Color.white);
    jp.add(tf); // adding JtextField (JTextField tf = new JTextField(30);)
    add(jp);        
}
```

and my `render()` is like this (just for testing purpose).

```
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy(); // tehdään uusi bufferi

    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    int R = (int) (Math.random( )*256);
    int G = (int)(Math.random( )*256);
    int B= (int)(Math.random( )*256);
    Color randomColor = new Color(R, G, B);
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.drawString("Arvaa sana", 100 , 100);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 50, leveys, korkeus);
    g.setColor(randomColor);
    g.setFont(h);
//  g.drawLine(0,0,liikey*2-1,liikex);
    for(int i = 0; i < salat.size(); i ++) {
        g.drawString(salat.get(i),liikex+rand.nextInt(50),liikey+rand.nextInt(50));
    }
    System.out.println(liikex + " " + liikey);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
```

I can get the textfield to be displayed on top at the start, but then it disappears.
Anyone knows if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Active Rendering (`BufferStrategy`) and Swing's passive rendering algorithm are not compatible with each other. You will either need to use the Swing API OR the `BufferStrategy` but not both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't draw directly in a JFrame
- Instead, if you need to draw a background image, do so in the paintComponent method of a JPanel. This will likely work much better than using BufferStrategy for your purposes.
- Then you can add components, such as your JTextField to this JPanel.
- And then add this JPanel to your JFrame.
- Always call the super's paintComponent method in your own paintComponent method override.
- Be careful to never dispose of a Graphics object given to you from the JVM, such as the one passed into your paintComponent method.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 800;
   private static final int PREF_H = 600;
   private static final Font PROMPT_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD,
         24);
   private Paint gradientPaint;
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

   public BackgroundPanel() {
      int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
      int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
      int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
      Color color1 = new Color(red, green, blue);
      red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
      green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
      blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
      Color color2 = new Color(red, green, blue);

      gradientPaint = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, 20, 20, color2, true);

      JLabel promptLabel = new JLabel("Input:");
      promptLabel.setFont(PROMPT_FONT);
      add(promptLabel);
      add(textField);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setPaint(gradientPaint);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.setFont(PROMPT_FONT);
      g.drawString("Arvaa sana", 100, 100);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      BackgroundPanel mainPanel = new BackgroundPanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("BackgroundPanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: As i said i am pretty new to java programming and always been using that bufferstrategy thing. Maybe i been wrong. Have to learn about that paintComponent thing. Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: @henryheino: Please don't misinterpret my reply -- nobody, least of all I, ever said that your question was stupid as it is not a stupid question. These types of rendering are used for different purposes. What is the purpose of your drawing? Complex animation? Or more of a simple background image? Please see edit to my answer for an example of what I was mentioning.

Comment: On this case its that random words are flying across screen. and you need to type them to remove. so is that paintCompnent thing better for it?

Comment: Basically i have whole finnish dictionary on arraylist. Then program picks 10 of them and flys them around window. and you need to type that word to remove it from screen.

Comment: This is basically just programming training for me.. i got the words flying around screen. but then i was stuck

Answer (score 0):

this is basically whole thing i got done now.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class teksti extends JFrame implements Runnable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
ArrayList<String> sanat = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> salat = new ArrayList<String>();
String dir =  System.getProperty("user.dir");
String pathname = dir  + "\\src\\kotus_sanat.txt";
Random rand = new Random();
Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);
String syote,salasana,salasana2;
int leveys=500,korkeus=500;
int liikex=300, liikey=300;
Font h = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18);
JTextField tf = new JTextField(30);
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
JFrame jf = new JFrame();


  public teksti() {

    setTitle("Hirsipuu");
    setSize(leveys,korkeus);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setBackground(Color.white);
    jp.add(tf);
    add(jp);

}

public static void main(String args[]){
     teksti teksti = new teksti();
     teksti.start();

}


private void start() {
    run();

}


public void run() {


    sanat = lataa();
    System.out.println(pathname);

    System.out.println(sanat.size() + " sanaa ladattu..");
    int sanoja=sanat.size();



    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    salat.add(sanat.get(rand.nextInt(sanoja)));
    }
    System.out.println("salasana on " + salasana);
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime(); // fps sälää
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    double delta = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    int updates = 0;
    requestFocus();

    boolean running=true;
    while (running){
         long now = System.nanoTime();
         delta += (now-lastTime) / ns;
         lastTime = now;
         while ( delta >= 1) {
            update();
            updates++;
            delta--;    
        }
        render();
         frames++;

         if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            setTitle("Hirsipuu"+ "    |    " + updates + " ups " +   frames + " fps" );
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }   
    }
 }

 private void update() {
    liikex = liikex + 1;
    liikey= liikey - 4;
    if (liikey>korkeus)
        liikey = 1;
    if (liikex>leveys)
        liikex= 1;
    if (liikey<20)
        liikey = korkeus;


 }
 private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy(); // tehdään uusi bufferi

    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }


    int R = (int) (Math.random( )*256);
    int G = (int)(Math.random( )*256);
    int B= (int)(Math.random( )*256);
    Color randomColor = new Color(R, G, B);
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();



g.drawString("Arvaa sana", 100 , 100);

g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillRect(0, 50, leveys, korkeus);
    g.setColor(randomColor);
    g.setFont(h);
//  g.drawLine(0,0,liikey*2-1,liikex);
    for(int i = 0; i < salat.size(); i ++) {
    g.drawString(salat.get(i),  liikex+rand.nextInt(50),liikey+rand.nextInt(50));
        }
    System.out.println(liikex + " " + liikey);

 g.dispose();
 bs.show();


  g.dispose();
 }






private void stop() {


}



private void vertaa() {
    System.out.println("Anna sana niin tarkastaan onko se oikea suomenkielinen sana: ");
    syote = lukija.next();

    boolean oikea = false;
    int i = 0;
    int z = 0;
    while (i < sanat.size()) { 
        if (syote.equals(sanat.get(i))) {
            oikea = true;
            System.out.println (syote + " on oikea suomalainen sana.");
            break;

        }
        else{



         }

        }
    if (!oikea) {
        System.out.println(syote + " ei ole oikea suomalainen sana.");
    }


 }



 public ArrayList<String> lataa() {



    String line = null;

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathname));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sanat.add(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sanat;
    }


}

             vertaa() is not used.
```